# Apex, Null Check

Tags: apex, soql

How to check if this query has return any record or not?

```
Account accnt = [SELECT Id FROM account WHERE Id =: accId limit 1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries return a `List`.

Adding `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query puts us into a special case. The query will either return 0 or 1 row. If there's only a single record returned, Salesforce allows you to assign the result of a query to a single SObject instance. The downside, though, is that if there are no rows, you'll get an exception (no rows for assignment).

Technically, you don't even need the `LIMIT 1` here, since you're querying based on a single Id (Id values are unique, there will never be 2 records with the same Id). If you don't use `LIMIT 1`, and your query returns more than one record, you'll get a similar exception (more than 1 row for assignment to SObject).

Storing the result of a query in a `List` (here, you'd use a `List<Account>`) is the safe way to handle queries (even when you only expect a single record).

Lists can store any number of objects (including 0). So if you store the result of your query in a list and you call the `size()` method (one of the methods provided by the `List` 'class'), and it returns `0`, then you know your query returned no results. Alternatively, the `isEmpty()` method would also work.

Comment: I think your explanation is a little confusing as you seem to indicate LIMIT 1 would be causing the exception, when it is actually the assignment to an SObject rather than SObject array variable. I suggest a small update is warranted.

Comment: @PhilW Edited. Is it a bit clearer now?

Answer (score 1):

If you assign it to a single instance of Account it'll throw an Exception`(List has no rows for assignment)` if there are no results returned matching the query.
So you should always use:
it with a list & check if the returned data has any rows or not.

```
List<Account> accntList = [Select Id From Account LIMIT 1];
        if(accntList.IsEmpty()){
         //RETURNED 0 RESULTS
           //..dosomething
        }
```

And if the SOQL returned at least one record you can reference it with accntList[0].

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the Winter 21 Release, we can use the Safe Navigation Operator (?.) to replace explicit, sequential checks for null references:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm?impact=

For example, we can write

```
String someName = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :someId]?.Name;
```

The *someName* variable will be set to NULL if an account with Id *someId* does not exist.  If an account is found, *someName* will be set to the value of the Name field on the account.

Comment: Whilst you are pointing out a valuable addition to Apex, it isn't directly relevant here since the OP appears to want the whole Account, not just its name.

Answer (score -2):

you can check it in many ways like

**by simply using IsEmpty() function on list**

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name, LogoID__c FROM Account WHERE URL_Code__c = :accountURL LIMIT 1];
if(!accs.isEmpty()){
//Your logic
}
```

**or by using size() function on list**

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, LogoID__c FROM Account WHERE URL_Code__c = :accountURL LIMIT 1];

if(accounts.size() > 0) {
// your logic
}
```

**and in your case you can directly use {!=null}**

```
Account accnt = [SELECT Id FROM account WHERE Id =: accId limit 1];
if(accnt!=null){
//your logic
}
```

**If you find this solution is helpful for you please mark best answer.**

Comment: Last one will be no use, because if there is no such account in org, the exception will be thrown before if-clause condition: `System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject`